# What is the resistance force of a ramp?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, terminology, distance

I know that the effort force is what you exert on the object, the effort distance is the length you walk on the ramp, and the resistance distance is the height that I traveled (or height of the ramp), but what is the resistance force. Below is a sketch of this:

[image]

Comment: Physicists usually are not aware of such namings. We have distance, force and work. And resistance is only one form of a force acting on an object sitting/moving on a ramp. If you are standing on the ramp it is the static friction that work against the component of your weight. If you are moving on a ramp (up./down) it is the kinetic friction that will resist against your motion.

Comment: Please make a sketch of the setup to make it clear. It might even explain the force you are looking for...

Comment: @Steeven I added one, I hope it makes sense

Comment: Aha, yes, thank you. In that case your missing force is the *normal force*. The force that the slide pushes back with perpendicularly up from the surface. And also remember gravity, which also works against your upwards push

Comment: @Steeven Isn't normal force something completely different from resistance force (Fr and Fn), but you bring up gravity; would it be the weight of the object I am pushing?

Comment: As @Benjamin points out, I've never heard the term *resistance force* before in this regard. I can just see which forces you are missing from the sketch. What you call them, doesn't really matter

Comment: But no, it is not different, if I understand the term correctly - normal force may indeed resist the motion. Just think about the case where you push against a vertical wall.

Comment: @Steeven: I would have suspected *resistance force* to be the *frictional force* (which is due to normal force: $F_\text{friction}=\mu F_\text{normal}\cos\theta$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nomenclature isn't standard - we don't talk about *effort* and *resistance* when dealing with these sorts of problems in physics.

Having said this, the *resistance force* is obviously meant to be the gravitational force, $F_g = mg$, and it acts downwards:

[image: Forces]

Your *effort force*, which I've labelled $F_e$ is given by:

$$ F_e = F_g \,\sin\theta $$